# How to retain local storage values when we click cancel button in onbeforeunload ( Page refresh/closing tab)

Tags: javascript, .net, blazor

This is the code for preventing page refresh/close tab, when clicking cancel button in dialog box local storage values are clearing. how to retain local storage values ?

```js
window.addEventListner('beforeunload', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = '';
})
```

Comment: Local storage does not clear itself, session storage does. This docs should help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event.
Also post a example how u store the data, this snippet does not give the clear picture.

Comment: @SARANSURYA  i am setting values from .net core (blazor) please check the below code  
                                                                                                                                        
   await _LocalStorage.SetAsync("name", currentInputValue);

Comment: @mplungjan no, i am not using sessionStorage. i am using localStorage which is available in .net core (blazor)

Comment: LocalStorage works fine with Blazor.  Previously cached values are not cleared on page navigation.  The problem is most likely related how and when you write values to localStorage. You'll need to share more of your code to help identify the problem.